# What's wrong in my 'if' statement I am getting a garbage value?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int arr[100], k, m;
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");

    float signall[10];
    signall[0] = atof(token);
    int i = 0;
    int ans[10];
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if(token != NULL)
        {
            signall[i+1] = atof(token);

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    for(k=0; k<10; k++)
    {
        printf("na: %f\n", signall[k]);
        printf("k: %d\n", k);

        if (signall[k]>=0.20 && signall[k]<=0.70)
            ans[k] = 0;
        if (signall[k]>=0.71 && signall[k]<=1.20)
            ans[k] = 1;
        if (signall[k]>=1.21 && signall[k]<=1.70)
            ans[k] = 2;
        if (signall[k]>=1.71 && signall[k]<=2.20)
            ans[k] = 3;
        if (signall[k]>=2.21 && signall[k]<=2.70)
            ans[k] = 4;
        if (signall[k]>=2.71 && signall[k]<=3.20)
            ans[k] = 5;
        if (signall[k]>=3.21 && signall[k]<=3.70)
            ans[k] = 6;
        if (signall[k]>=3.71 && signall[k]<=4.20)
            ans[k] = 7;
        if (signall[k]>=4.21 && signall[k]<=4.70)
            ans[k] = 8;
        if (signall[k]>=4.71 && signall[k]<=5.20)
            ans[k] = 9;
    }
    printf("%d", ans[4]);
    for (m=0; m<10; m++)
        printf("%d\n", ans[m]+1);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, and I am getting a garbage value at the fourth index of the array `ans`.

But I have even checked whether the elements are correct in array *signall* and they are placed correctly. I tried many things and modified the code, but still I am getting the same garbage value as output.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is not guaranteed to set a value. If `signal[k]` < 0.2 or > 5.2, no value will be set in `ans`.

In fact, if the value is 0.701 it will slip through the cracks. Remember that a float that you think is equal to 1.2 may actually be 1.2000001, so your `if` has quite a few gaps. You probably want it more like:

```
if (signall[k] <= 0.70) // Note handles value < 0.2 differently to your original
    ans[k] = 0;
else if (signal[k] <= 1.2)
    ans[k] = 1;
else if (signal[k] <= 1.7)
```

Comment: all the input values are equal to or below 5.2 so i did not add any condition greater than 5.2

Comment: so how can i change my code to get the correct answer??

Comment: i got the answer i just referred and added a f after my float values in if condition then it worked well anyways thank you for your help